# Applying Style at ListPlot

Tags: plotting, marker

My goal is to change color and size of the marker in ListPlot.I could change color of the marker.But I couldn't for the size. How to modify cord for this?(The Style has option for size but it didn't work for this case, which I don't know)

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2},Style[{3, 4}, Red]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2}, Style[{3, 4}, Red, PointSize @ .03]}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2}, Style[{3, 4}, Red, AbsolutePointSize @ 15]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A variation:

**Using `PointValuePlot`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
n = 12;
vals = RandomReal[{1, 4}, {n, 3}];
data = {#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ vals

PointValuePlot[data, {"Size"}
 , Frame -> False
 , Axes -> True
 , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-0.1, 0.1} +
      MinMax[vals[[All, 3]] ]}], After]
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Using `BubbleChart`:**

```
    BubbleChart[vals
     , ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, r}, ColorData["Rainbow"][r]]
     , ChartLegends -> Placed[
       BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-0.1, 0.1} +
          MinMax[vals[[All, 3]] ]}], After]
     ]
```